# Assignment to expression using ternary operator

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to understand why the first one is OK,

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> filterExpression = null;
if (id.HasValue) filterExpression = w => w.Id == id.Value;
```

and this one complains:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> filterExpression = id.HasValue ? w => w.Id == id.Value : null;
```

In the second one, I'm receiving error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Id'". I can't see why "w" is not resolved as my class "Foo" in this case, since the expression definition on the left-side contains such information.

Thanks.

Comment: Because the right side of the assignment contains a complex expression, the lambda expression on the right cannot be resolved to a type. In order to make the expression compile, you have to give the compiler actual type information: `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> filterExpression = id.HasValue ? (Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>) (w => w.Id == id.Value) : null;`

Comment: @JonSkeet I disagree to the duplicate since the OP wants to assign null and not another expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement has several problems.

First, the symbol `w` is of type `MerketNews` and not `Foo`.

Second, you cannot define an expression using the (pseudo-)syntax

```
[ExpressionType] expr = [boolValue] ? [lambda] : null;
```

You must use

```
[ExpressionType] expr = [boolValue] ? [lambda] : ([ExpressionType])null;
```

In your case:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> filterExpression = id.HasValue ? w => w.Id == id.Value : (Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>)null;
```

Comment: Sorry, I was renaming it to 'Foo' and missed that line. Thanks for the reply, now I see why!